# Pregnant on tier 2 visa, delivery in my home country

Tags: united-kingdom, dependent-visa

I am a dependent on UK skilled worker visa with BRP leave to remain, pregnant and I want to deliver in my country (Jordan). Will the baby be able to file for an ILR at the same time as me or will they have to wait 5 years after their application?

Comment: From the terminology in the question this relates to the UK. Your newborn would need a visa to return with you to the UK. Thereafter AFAIK if a *child dependent visa holder’s* parent is in the process of applying for ILR, they can include the dependant child in the same application.

Comment: I have a visa in UK and want to deliver in Jordan